# what is the best practice for multiple threads writing to one file

Tags: multithreading, file, thread-safety

I'm writing a multi-threaded program and all these threads should write their data to a single file.
these threads only writing different strings for some kind of append-only logging

whats the best practice for sharing a file between threads for out put?

Comment: Personally I would have all the threads write the data into some shared container and then have another thread that just extracts the data from the container and writes it to the file.

Comment: Make sure there is locking mechanism in place for file writes.

Comment: The best practice is to avoid sharing and contention.

Comment: Either a mutex to get exclusive access to the file. Or use a writer thread and post the data to an in memory queue that the writer thread processes, you will still need to lock the queue but for a much shorter time.

Comment: The question needs more specifics to be answerable. Are there distinct records in the file that can be updated independently? Append-only log? Or...?

Comment: thanks to all of you for productive answers. these threads only writing different strings to file. It's some kind of logging and append-only

Comment: @Behrang You need to use a mutex to synchronize the file access then. Or even better use another thread that is responsible for writing to the file only and reads from a synchronized queue that is fed by the other threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For logging (for future questions, make sure you put that information into the question rather than just a comment) there's a strong preference to not have the threads do file access they don't have to; as it means that logging negatively impacts performance for the rest of that thread.

For that reason, NathanOliver's suggestion of having the threads write to a shared container and then one dedicated to dumping that container to file would probably be the best option for you.